# Migrating my MVC 3 application to MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, migration, razor

I really do not know what to do, I'm following [this article](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes) that shows how to migrate my MVC 3 application manually .

I followed **all the steps** but when running my application the following error occurs:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   Microsoft.Web.Samples.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type Microsoft.Web.Samples.PreApplicationStartCode
>   threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +423
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization
>   method Start on type Microsoft.Web.Samples.PreApplicationStartCode
>   threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9079340 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +256
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237

**I looked through the code, but I see no reference to System.Web.WebPages.Razor in version 1.0 version 2.0 only.**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use NuGet and add the package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc (Microsoft Asp.Net Mvc 4). This should upgrade your references. See:

> https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc

You will need to upgrade the assembly references in your web.config.

**Remove from the root web.config:**

```xml
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</assemblies>
```

**Add to the root web.config:**

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

**Views/Web.Config:**

Change Razor from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0:

```xml
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

<pages validateRequest="false"
       pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
       pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
       userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: I've lost VS 2010 intellisense support on razor page after changes. forexample; "@model MyClass" is look like wrong but work. what should I do to take back intellisense support?

Comment: Go to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache and 2) Hit Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: In addition, I also had to remove a `<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>` that I had in my root config.

Comment: I am getting this same problem after going through the steps mentioned above. I get compile-time errors of 

 1. Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl' AND
 2. Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage AND
 3. Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage

Though this error is only relevant to ONE of my MVC projects. The others build fine, and I've tested that the classes mentioned in the list above actually exist in code. 

Hmmmm... this is an error that should be occurring with all of my upgrade projects and NOT just one. 

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to update the references in `Views\Web.Config`? The references in it is used to build the view pages.

Comment: I already checked this, as you can see in the comments below.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed you have MVC3 Intranet web application, when upgrade from MVC3 to MVC4 using NuGet, your application now references System.Web.WebPages.Razor Version 2.0.0.0, NOT System.Web.WebPages.Razor Version 1.0.0.0 anymore. Here is my way of resolving the reference.

There are two places to fix:

1. In the root web.config,

   ```
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
     <assemblies>
       . . .
       <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
       . . .
     </assemblies>
   </compilation>
   ```

change Version=**1**.0.0.0 to Version=**2**.0.0.0

So your new reference will look like this:

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        . . .
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        . . .
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

1. **In the Views folder**, there is web.config file. Inspecting this file you will see it references Version 1. **Replace the whole web.config file in Views folder with a new web.config file**. Make a backup of the old web.config file, just in case. To get a brand new web.config for the Views folder, you create a new MVC4 application for intranet. Go to the Views folder. Copy the Web.Config file from the Views folder of the new application to the Views folder of the broken application.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you globally searched for *System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0* in your entire solution? Do you still reference `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` (Version 1.0.0.0)? Do you reference `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` Version 2.0.0.0?

---

**[Update]** I finally ran into the same issue. It seems like one of the NuGet packages I installed and uninstalled didn't entirely remove the reference to `System.Web.Razor` it used. Cleaning the solution didn't help because the DLL wasn't used directly by the web application. I finally got it to work by manually deleting the entire *bin* directory ...

Comment: I looked in my entire solution, there is no point in reference to version 1.0. Even the edited file .csproj and .sln looking for this reference. But I not found.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the AspNetSprite packages as suggested above does not solve the problem for me. But adding theses lines on the runtime\assemblyBinding section of the root web.config file works :

```
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the web.config inside your views folder.

UPDATE:

This bit looks suspcious.

> Microsoft.Web.Samples.PreApplicationStartCode

Are you referencing any sample application libraries, like MVC futures or anything like that?

Comment: Already checked all, there is nothing pointing to version 1.0. See the root Web.config in: https://gist.github.com/1265901

Comment: I do not understand. I did not find anything in the web.config with `Microsoft.Web.Samples.PreAppliaction...` I use `Elmah`, `Melezes`, `Mvc.Mailer` and `AutoMapper`

Comment: I also use these DLLs .. `Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationFramework` and `Microsoft.Web.Samples.SpriteHelper` .. But I do not understand how it can cause this error. If that's what's causing it.

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa - Well, clearly those dll's are referencing Razor and asking for verison 1.0.  The fact that the namespaces are the same are clearly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My application used a third-party package, the AspNetSprites-MvcAndRazorHelper. Reinstalled this package and the error of the reference was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is another Nuget package that u can use to upgrade mvc 3 to mvc 4 
https://nuget.org/packages/UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple, when you update to MVC 4.0.0.0 ,but the webconfig in the solution still points to MVC 3.0.0.0.0.
so just replace MVC version 3.0.0.0.0.  by 4.0.0.0.0

Do the same with other assemblies, to check the version of assembly , check properties of the respective assembly in references in your project.