# Deployment of ASP.NET MVC 4 app failed could not load type

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a asp.net mvc 4 application taht uses a ApiController.

But when i try to access the web api, i'm getting this error.

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Razor.Parser.SyntaxTree.CodeSpan' from assembly >'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I already take a lok to the bin folder and i see the System.Web.Razor.dll I also add this to the web config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Does any member of Stack Overflow have this problem?

What i'm missing in my deploy?

Comment: running in the same issue moving the webapi controllers in a separate assembly.

Comment: temporary fixed removing razor's dependentAssembly from web.config 0_0

Comment: Seems like WEB API depends on both versions of System.Web.Razor, I'm temporary fixed the problem adding one version to my bin folder and the other one inside the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Check the web.config file in Views folder AND the line

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0 ...
```

in the root web.config. See my note in [this this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668252/migrating-my-mvc-3-application-to-mvc-4/15142264#15142264).

Answer (score 0):

I finally just create a new asp.net mvc 4 project from scratch and move in all my code.